# Is there a reliable 3 text box SSN input component which handles both continuous typing and tabbing?

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have an SSN field on an HTML form.

I'd like to implement the user experience of seeing 3 boxes and the middle one being shorter because the well known format ###-##-#### goes with it.

On the one hand I could automatically change focus to the next box when the previous one has valid numbers in it.  This would allow typing it in one go...

But on the other hand if you're someone like me (and maybe it's just me I don't know) when I see multiple boxes I naturally hit the tab key.

I've used sites that get this kind of this *wrong* and it's a poor experience.

Does anyone have a reliable way to do this backed by successful real world usage?

Comment: put a timer on the auto-tab so that if the user hits tab within a certain time after that (say .5sec), it's ignored

Comment: Why not use a single text box with a masked input? http://jsfiddle.net/ssking44/SCzVP/